# nhibernate mapping error

Tags: nhibernate-mapping

I have view width columns:
ID,
TREE_NODE_ID,
ATTRIB_ID,
INT_VALUE,
DATE_VALUE,
STRING_VALUE,

and table:
ID,
PARENT_ID,
TREE_ID,

```
public interface ITreeNode
    {
        long Id { get; set; }
        ITreeNode Parent { get; set; }
// I want to get:
        IDictionary<IAttribute, IAllTreeNodeValues> SpecTreeNodeValues { get; set; }
    }

public interface IAllTreeNodeValues
    {
        long Id { get; set; }
        ITreeNode TreeNode { get; set; }
        IAttribute Attribute { get; set; }
        long? IntValue { get; set; }
        DateTime DateValue { get; set; }
        string StringValue { get; set; }
    }

fragment of mapping file:
    <map name="SpecTreeNodeValues" lazy="true"> 
      <key column="TREE_NODE_ID"/>
      <index-many-to-many column="ATTRIB_ID" class="Attribute"/>
      <many-to-many class="AllTreeNodeValues"/>
    </map>
```

got an error: An association from the table SpecTreeNodeValues refers to an unmapped class: GeneralData.Entity.Atribute

Comment: check name of your class GeneralData.Entity.Atribute, maybe you mean `GeneralData.Entity.Attribute`. Update question if the problem not in class name. Class `Atribute` unmapped

Comment: When mapping: <map name="SpecTreeNodeValues" lazy="true"> I get SQl query from table SpecTreeNodeValues, but it must get data from table ALL_TREE_NODE_VALUES, how can I fix it

Comment: when set <map name="SpecTreeNodeValues" lazy="true" table="ALL_TREE_NODE_VALUES"> got error: Foreign key (FK49254D5DDFC2DD97:ALL_TREE_NODE_VALUES [elt])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (ALL_TREE_NODE_VALUES [TREE_NODE_ID, ATTRIB_ID])

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled Attribute here:

`<index-many-to-many column="ATTRIB_ID" class="Atribute"/>`